# Best practice on how to integrate a settings file for the init of an own python package?

Tags: python, django

I have created an own python package (let's call it OwnRep) within which I need to use config settings like
database access address, credentials, etc.

I want to use the own package in other projects. Now, what I want to avoid is that my
credentials are hardcoded within OwnRep.Therefore, I have started to think about intialising
my OwnRep package with some sort of settings setup similar to Django and SciPy, so that 
the package's setup are set dynamically.

Any solution proposals for this? 
A conceptual picture is attached as a link
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHRQg.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the credentials in your environment. It is safer. Then create a file called settings.py or anything you want and do something like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'your_engine',
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats definitely valid. However, do you know what is the best solution in case of nested structures to save?

For example, if you save two database names?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to make sure all required credentials (api_key, username, password) is supplied during instantiation of your own package. This can be done by passing actual information to your own package or by reading from environment variable.

Let's take few real world example:

1. Sendgrid:

```
import sendgrid
import os
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import *

sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(api_key=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
from_email = Email("test@example.com")
to_email = To("test@example.com")
subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
content = Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Python")
mail = Mail(from_email, to_email, subject, content)
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
```

In snippet above, for us to be able to access sendgrid API we need to provide api_key. The api_key can be received from environment variable called SENDGRID_API_KEY even though the implementation behind also do exact same thing. please check https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/sendgrid/sendgrid.py for more implementation details.

2. Oy-Client (Python package that i created):

```
from oy import build_client
oy_client = build_client("https://sandbox.oyindonesia.com/staging/partner", "username", "api-key")
oy_client.get_balance()
```

In snippet above, for us to be able to access the API we need to provide base_url (where were point it) and api_key.

With both of this example, we can achieve portability and security on our own code according to https://12factor.net/config. And there's no need to hardcoded the configuration / credentials inside your own package.